# Level-0 spells for Duskblade?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

I was creating a duskblade with the *Player's Handbook 2*, and on page 98 spells for the Duskblade are listed, but there are no level 0 spells to chose from... (I'm guessing there is another source for Duskblade spells, since *shocking grasp* is mentioned to be a good spell for the class earlier in the book, but is not listed under Duskblade spells).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Duskblade's spell list is stealthily hiding on p. 24 of Players Handbook 2, after the sample starting package. The 0th level spells are listed there.

Your options from that book are Acid Splash, Disrupt Undead, Ray of Frost, and Touch of Fatigue. (Shocking Grasp is also in this spell list.)

These spells are ***NOT*** listed in the Duskblade spell list on p. 98. That list only covers new PHB 2 spells, and none of the 0th level spells are new to PHB 2.